# WordPress Multisite Question

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I want to add a subdomain to all my WordPress sites in a WP MU.

For example, I have: `example.com`. When adding a new site to be: `demo.example.com/newsite1`

I don't want to create a new user or WordPress Installation.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with domain mapping and a compatible hosting account.  There are a few good domain mapping plugins available that may work for you with a little configuration.  I have used [Domain Mapping plugin](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/domain-mapping)by Barry, as well as [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://ocaoimh.ie/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).  There is also the Multi-Domains plugin from wpmudev, which allows the creation of subdomains at your primary or mapped domains.  Details are available at premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-domains/ (sorry, stackexchange won't let me provide more than two hyperlinks in my answer).  You can also always try visiting the WordPress Plugin Directory or hitting Google for other options.

Comment: thanks but I think there must be a .htaccess hack, or some php codes, I'm currently searching and trying to do this...

Answer (score 0):

yes when you create the subdomain it will be under your login.

Comment: how? should I edit my .htaccess file too?